# How to add footer div in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In my React web app, I have the body as follows in index.html :

```
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

and inside index.js, my render method is as follows:

```
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history} routes={routes} />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

I want to be able to add a footer div inside index.html and index.js so that I could style it properly and keep it at the bottom of my page according to the dynamic height of root. How do I implement a footer div?

Comment: You could add an additional div `<div id="footer"></div>` and render to that separately with `render(<Footer />, document.getElementById('footer'))`.

Comment: I already have my render method above. How do I also render a footer component?

Comment: Yes, you're right, but there is nothing stopping you from rendering a separate component into a new `div` below your `root` if you want to.

Comment: seems to work, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an additional div `<div id="footer"></div>` below your `root` and render to that separately:

```
render(<Footer />, document.getElementById('footer'))
```

Comment: This is not working for me, ideally it should as i have added another div in html itself.